# Is use of list, member functions, and classes correct in my code?

Tags: c++, class, hyperlink, containers

I had to return to C++, after coding in MATLAB. I am missing a few things. Anyways, I wrote a code to create expandable list of person's first name, last name, and their age. By expandable, I mean, more entries can be made later, if required.

It instantiates first name, last name and age of 5 persons. I need to make it expandable, and calculate average age of person's list. I used lists in my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {
    // Create a list of first names and initialize it with 5 first names
    std::list<string> firstname(new string[] { "Brad", "John", "Neptune",    "Kuh", "Dhar", "Rock" });

    // Iterate over and display first names
    for (string val : firstname)
        std::cout << val << ",";
            std::cout << std::endl;

    // Create a list of last names and initialize it with 5 last  names
    std::list<string> lastname(new string[] { "Mish", "Jims", "Nepers", "Yho", "Har", "Ock" });

    // Iterate over and display first names
    for (string val2 : lastname)
        std::cout << val2 << ",";
            std::cout << std::endl;


    // Create an empty list of ages pf persons
    std::list<int> ages(5, {34, 56, 57, 91, 12});

    // Iterate over the list and display ages
    for (int val1 : ages)
        std::cout << val1 << ",";
        std::cout << std::endl;

    // Compute average age
    for (int jj=0; jj <5; jj++)
    agesum = age(jj) + age(jj+1);
    avage = agesum/(jj+1);
    return 0;
}
```

However it does not execute, and gives errors. Could you please correct the code, and give me feedback on what is going on?

Comment: Are you working from a tutorial or a from book?

Comment: Hi Galik, I am writing code by searching online examples.

Comment: Also here is a link to an online manual. Its explanations are not always easy for beginners but its examples are good. Here is how to use `std::list` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list

Comment: if you want to initialize an `std::list<std::string>` type variable the easiest way is `std::list<std::string> x = { "abc", "def", ... };` The allocation is done automatically through the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were going for?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){

    std::vector<std::string> first_names {"Brad", "John", "Neptune", "Kuh", "Dhar", "Rock"};
    std::vector<std::string> last_names {"Mish", "Jims", "Nepers", "Yho", "Har", "Ock"};
    std::vector<int> ages {34, 56, 57, 91, 12};

    int avg_age = 0;

    for(int age : ages) avg_age += age;
    avg_age /= ages.size();


    if(first_names.size() == last_names.size()){
        for(int i = 0; i < first_names.size(); i++){

            std::cout << first_names[i] << " " << last_names[i] << "\n";

        }
    }
    std::cout << "average age: " << avg_age << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @ donpsabance Thanks, I was looking for sth similar. Is the code expandable to more than 1000 people?

Comment: @Digvijay, according to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/max_size/), the max elements for vector is 1073741823. So yea